# Include all column from select to groupBy mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query into which I need to add all columns from select to groupBy clause. This is just an example, I've around 20-25 columns to be selected and a long query to deal with.

```
Eg = SELECT contact.id as id, contact.name as name, 
       IF ( contact.type = 'type1', NULL, contact.organization_name), 
       contact.occupation as occupation, contact.gender as gender 
     FROM table_name 
     WHERE <condition> 
     GROUP BY contact.id.
```

What I have in an array is this :

```
$select = array(
  'id' => 'contact.id as id',
  'name' => 'contact.name as name',
  'type' => IF ( contact.type = 'type1', NULL, contact.organization_name),
  'occupation' => 'contact.occupation as occupation',
  'gender' => 'contact.gender as gender',
);

$groupBy = 'GROUP BY contact.id';
```

Now I have to dynamically update `groupBy` clause to include all the columns from the `$select` array from php code.

I've done this :

```
foreach ($select as $key => $val) {
  $alias = explode(' as ', $val);
  if ($alias[0] != 'contact_a.id') {
    $selectColAlias[] = $alias[0];
  }
}

$groupBy .= ', ' . implode(', ', $selectColAlias);
```

This is happening correctly if `type` is not included in the `$select` array.

Is there anything which would populate my groupBy clause to include all the columns from the select clause ?

As I have `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode enabled. This gives an error if the above thing is not done.

Comment: Note: I can't disable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode to avoid this.

Comment: Why not make the SELECT 'non-dynamic'?

Comment: @Strawberry the columns in `$select` is what I have(can't change that), need to modify `$groupBy` with this array

Comment: Do you have only one `IF` in select clause ?

Comment: no, there are multiple such stmts, its just an eg, I was just looking if there is any alternate way - apart from what I was trying to include things from select to group by(may be from mysql perspertive ?)